# Image Uploading to Web Service from iOS

Tags: ios, photos, sharing

I often want to make a picture available on the internet, without wanting it as part of my Twitter stream or Facebook account etc.  For example, posting a screenshot to a thread on a forum or just to include in an email without sending an attachment.

I'm happy for the pic to be public, but don't necessarily want it to be associated to me if people stumble across it, or have it included with photos I actually care about on services like Flickr etc.  I just want to throw it up to an image hosted and dump it without a trail, in the easiest and quickest way possible.

The closest I have found is an app called [Picup](http://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/picup/id354101378?mt=8), which throws a photo onto Imgur without any logging in and captioning etc etc.  If it also had the ability to scale it down to half sized it may be enough, but it doesn't, and as such pics are full sized which increases upload speed and makes the picture potentially too large for sensible linking to on sites that won't auto-scale it.

So, what I am after will ideally meet the following criteria:

- Allow me to take a photo, or use a camera roll image
- Resize it automatically via a preset preference (Say max 400 in largest dimension)
- Upload it to am image hosting service that does not require me to have an account or log in
- Present me with the resulting URL in a way that makes copying it simple, perhaps via a big fat COPY URL button, or automatically selecting the text etc
- *Optional* - provide links for common uses of the URL - compose email, send tweet etc.

Imagine a scenario; I see a ridiculous haircut in Wallmart, I want to snap it, throw it up, send it to friends, then abandon it so I never have to care about who finds it by accident later with my name against it, and never need to go pruning such childish photos from my genuinely useful and wanted pics such as those in Instagram etc.

Answer (score 1):

You could check out [CloudApp](http://www.getcloudapp.com). It started out on desktop but there are a couple good mobile clients as well, namely [Stratus](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/stratus/id438805266?mt=8) and [Cloud2go](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/cloud2go/id388386211?mt=8).

These apps don't do any sort of editing. But CloudApp's backend automatically scales images when viewing on a screen that's too small to display them at their native size. Additionally, they provide a 'direct link' option for embedding images directly.

Comment: +1 for Cloudapp and Stratus (Cloud2go has issues with iOS 5). Great service and even greater company; just a bunch of great guys with a great sense of craftsmanship.

Comment: CloudApp seems OK, only the non-resizing means that while it may look OK as scaled to your device size, a retina iphone screenshot should still be enormous is linked to say on here via your normal desktop browser.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into [skitch](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/skitch-for-ipad/id490505997?mt=8) for iOS? I use it extensively for screen shots and it has a sketch.com hosting option and also works well with [Evernote](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/evernote/id281796108?mt=8) and other hosting services. The latter has acquired the former, so you might not be able to make a new account, but you can try skitch out for free on [Mac OS](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/skitch/id425955336?mt=12) as well as [iOS](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/skitch-for-ipad/id490505997?mt=8).

I could also see using [posterous spaces](https://posterous.com/) for this sort of thing - they do have an app, but you can just email photos to the web site and it handles thumbnails and processing on the server end of things. Using the service is dead simple and quite pretty layouts are included for free.

Comment: Skitch seems to be iPad only, but it looks interesting.

Comment: Posterous spaces requires an account.  OK, I could create a ridiculous one which may not be obviously linked to me, but by association if all the pics are clearly associated it could do.  I want anonymous.

Comment: Posterous makes an anonymous account for you when you email a photo in. You can stay anonymous by not registering or registering and deleting pictures when you no longer need them. You can also make your space private which means if you share an image link - it works, but someone can't reverse back to other related pictures other than by tracking your broadcast mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

You sound like you're looking for a native app, but the web app you access at http://imgur.com/ sounds like the feature set you want. Upload from your camera roll, not linked to you, and you get a url you can paste wherever you want.
[image]

Comment: That would work, a=only it doesn't scale the image down, and the job of subsequently copying the url is a little messy.  Also, it will only allow for existing photos, not let me take a fresh one.

Comment: I don't get the "fresh one" problem. As soon as you take a picture, isn't it available in Photo Roll? Obviously you can't post a photo that doesn't exist, but as soon as you use the camera app to create the picture, it's available for posting.

Comment: It's the flow, if I need to take a quick snap of something, and want to throw up a reduced size version onto a site without needing a login, without it being part of a gallery of all my other pics, and without the source sitting in my camera roll or photo stream leaving me to neeed to remember to remove it.  The end result I am loking for is quick and dirty disposable photo uploading, minimal effort, minimal management.

Answer (score 0):

I came across [TinyPic](http://tinypic.com/) while looking at this. It seems to fit the bill, but without registering you can only upload one pic at a time.

[image: TinyPic]

Answer (score 0):

Photobucket?

> App Summary: Take Photobucket with you on your iPhone! Upload all your special moments directly to your Photobucket albums. Existing photos AND VIDEOS can be uploaded from your camera roll, and new shots and clips can be uploaded from within the camera app. Looking for entertainment during moments of downtime? Find Stuff categories have billions of photos and videos for you to view, and you can download photos to your phone for FREE to use as wallpapers, contact IDs, and more. You can even share your photos, videos, and albums to Facebook or Twitter right from your phone, fast and easy.

http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/photobucket/id314439840?mt=8